# Azure Functions HTTP Trigger : How to return exception from python worker log to the API caller

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm new to Azure functions 
Wished to know how to return exception from python worker log to the API caller .

In a HTTP Trigger with COSMOS DB binding , on firing an insert call to the binding , if data already exists , it fails with

"System.Private.CoreLib:  Exception while executing function: Functions.insertEntityData. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Entity with the specified id already exists in the system."

How can this message be sent back to the end user ? It is not getting captured anywhere.

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, cosmosdata: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        message = ""
        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
        entity_name = req.route_params['entity']
        status_code = 500
        payload = req.get_json()
        if payload:
            try:
                logging.info(payload)
                resultant = cosmosdata.set(func.Document.from_dict(payload))
                logging.info(resultant)
                status_code = 200
                message = "Insert Successful to %s" % (entity_name)

            except Exception as e:
                return func.HttpResponse(str(e), status_code=500)
        else:
            status_code = 400
            message = "Please pass data in the POST Request"
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(str(e), status_code=500)

    return func.HttpResponse(message, status_code=500)
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your Function's code so we can understand how you are using the Cosmos DB binding? Cosmos DB output binding does an Upsert operation when saving items, not Create. Does your collection have Unique Keys enabled?

Comment: I've put in the code snippet. Yes unique key is enabled and that's why it is prompting the error when reinserting already existing key value. I just wish to capture the error and return to the user

Answer (score 1):

The try / catch block is not working because you're using an Output binding to Cosmos Db, which is the one that is failing. However, it also looks weird to me because by default it performs and Upsert operation.

I believe the problem relates to your partition Key defined in the function.json file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#input---python-examples

Comment: Oh, I can see why it is not getting captured in try catch . I've not provided the partition key in the function.json . And actually this is the behaviour I was trying to achieve  .  I just wished to capture the error message being thrown from the binding , if that's possible

Comment: I don't think it is, because it's handled internally by azure functions.